# Круговые диаграммы для объектов в ObjectManager

Tags: javascript, json, yandex-maps-api

Какой должен быть формат json для ObjectManager

https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager

Что выводились метки в формате круговой диаграммы

https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/geoobjects-docpage/#geoobjects__piechart

Answer (score 1):

Требования такие же как и к использованию круговых диаграмм в кластеризаторе.
Цвет берется из цвета метки, так что достаточно добавить опцию OM
`clusterIconLayout: 'default#pieChart'`
https://jsfiddle.net/Lw28pmrk/

Comment: Это не совсем то, что нужно. Нужны круговые диаграммы у объектов, а не у кластеров.

Answer (score 0):

В общем сам разобрался. Формат такой:

```js
{"type":"FeatureCollection",
 "features":[{
             "id":16,
             "type":"Feature",
             "geometry":{
                        "type":"Point",
                        "coordinates":["56.105127","37.608592"]
             },
             "properties":{
                          "name":"Пестово",
                          "iconContent":1,
                          "data":[{
                                "weight":30,
                                "color":"#0024a2"},
                                {
                                "weight":70,
                                "color":"#0028b2"}
                                ]
             },
             "options":{
                        "iconLayout":"default#pieChart",
                        "iconPieChartCoreRadius":10,
                        "iconPieChartRadius":20}
             }
]
}
```